# Transition possibillity rate of infinite well

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, fermis-golden-rule

Can the standard form of the Fermi golden rule be used to solve part (1) of this problem?

[image]

The standard form for a two state system is
\begin{equation*}
\Gamma_{i\rightarrow f}
=\frac{2\pi}{\hbar}|\langle f|H'|i\rangle|^2g(\hbar\omega)
\end{equation*}

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermi%27s_golden_rule

Comment: I’ve forgotten time-dependent perturbation theory, but I don’t think you can use a continuous approximation for the density of states when transitioning between such discrete states. As Wikipedia states, “Fermi's golden rule is a formula that describes the transition rate (the probability of a transition per unit time) from one energy eigenstate of a quantum system to a group of energy eigenstates **in a continuum**…”.

Comment: That is a poor interpretation of Fermi. The derivation of the Golden Rule actually makes no specification on the gaps between states, and gives formulae for the coefficients evolving in response to the perturbation in any case. It can even be generalized to deal with initial linear combination states.

Answer (score 1):

Fermi's golden rule presumes the following perturbing Hamiltonian where phase $\phi$ is an arbitrary constant.
$$
V(x,t)=H'(x)
\bigl(\exp(i\omega t+i\phi)+\exp(-i\omega t-i\phi)\bigr)
$$

So we have to rewrite $V(x,t)$ as
$$
V(x,t)=\frac{1}{2}
\left(x-\frac{L}{4}\right)^2
2\sin\omega t
$$
and put the $\frac{1}{2}$ in the matrix element.
Then it becomes $\frac{1}{4}$ when the matrix
element is squared. Hence for this problem
$$
\Gamma_{1\rightarrow2}=\frac{\pi}{2\hbar}
|M_{21}|^2
g(\hbar\omega)
$$
where
$$
|M_{21}|^2=\left|
\langle2|\left(x-\frac{L}{4}\right)^2|1\rangle
\right|^2
$$